# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 1 of null when using row.match

Tags: javascript

I have some code that I am working on that is meant to try and read from a name of a variable and a value from a csv file and pass it through to two separate arrays. I am getting an error that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at eval (eval at runAction (out1.js:254), <anonymous>:36:35)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.onCompleted (eval at runAction (out1.js:254), <anonymous>:29:17)
    at e (out1.js:218)
    at FileReader.l.onloadend (out1.js:218)
```

The code I have written so far is:

```
openFile({
    read: "Text",
    multiple: false,
    onCompleted: function(result){
        alert(result.contents);
        var name = [];
        var value = [];
        var i = 0, j = 0;
        
        var string = result.contents;
        var csvRows = string.split(/;|\n/); 
        
        var varNames = [];
        var varVals = [];

        csvRows.forEach(row => {
           
            
            var rowParts = row.match(/(.+),\s?(.+)/);
            
            // push adds the element to the end of the array
            // rowParts[0] is the whole match so rowParts[1] is the varName
            
            varNames.push(rowParts[1]);
            varVals.push(rowParts[2]);
        })
        for (i = 0; i < varNames.length; i++){
            alert(varNames[i]);
        }
        }})
```

The error seems to be appearing in this line because when I change the value inside the square brackets the '1' changes to whatever the number is changed to:

```
varNames.push(rowParts[1]);
varVals.push(rowParts[2]);
```

The csv file that I am trying to import is formatted as such:

```
"Variable Name 1", "Value 1"
"Variable Name 2", "Value 2"
"Variable Name 3", "Value 3"
```

For example, I have 3 variables called "a variable, b variable, c variable" and they have the values, "1,2,3" respectively.

The code is written in a web app that has a separate API and only uses the base javascript for what I am using at the moment. I have tried different methods and have come up against the same error. If anyone knows how to solve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.match()` can return `null`.

Comment: Sounds like `/(.+),\s?(.+)/` does not match one of your lines

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say that your CSV ends with a newline so the last element of `csvRows` is an empty string, hence `row.match(/(.+),\s?(.+)/)` doesn't match. Unfortunately we can't do much more than guessing since we don't know what `csvRows` contains.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas on how to solve the issue. I have added the details of how the csv file is laid out

Comment: @a_chr1s [That should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/75mnjfqo/).

Comment: So after a bit of testing the program seems to break when the file ends and the program doesn't move on but errors out because there is a null value. I think the resolution would be to break when there is a null input however i'm not sure of the best way to do this

Comment: @a_chr1s Sounds like my initial guess: "_If I had to take a guess, I'd say that your CSV ends with a newline so the last element of `csvRows` is an empty string_". You can manually remove that newline at the end of the file, or you could just check if `rowParts` is null and if so, skip that iteration. Something like `if (!rowParts) return;`.